# Native libraries with Jenkins

Tags: scala, jenkins, native, sbt

I am using Jenkins as my CI server for a project that makes use of a native library.  The project is in scala and I am using sbt to compile and run the unit tests. One of the libraries that I am using is a java (jni) wrapper around a c-library.

I have added the location of the library to the LD_LIBRARY_PATH and location of the jar to CLASSPATH in my .bashrc so that I can run the project and unit tests from the command line.

How do I do this for Jenkins?

Comment: Why do you need to pass information about native library to jenkins? What language/compiler is required for your project to compile? Generally speaking, please give more information about your case and explain what exactly is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have recently had a problem when copying artifacts from remote nodes, which was fixed by adding the following to the advanced setting "JVM options" of the relevant node:

**-Djava.library.path=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/**

This is quite simple and is obvious to anyone reviewing the settings, for example when replicating the node configuration to use a similar machine.  I do not recommend touching system- or user-wide scripts, in general.

Comment: No, but I guessed you simply need to add the proper directories to that path.

Comment: I have already tried giving -Djava.library.path=/.. as a jvm option in  Jenkins but it did not work.

Comment: I discovered a problem with permissions which I fixed and this solution now works. For completeness, under the 'build' section of Jenkins configuration, where 'build using sbt' is activated, in the text box 'JVM Flags' add  -Djava.library.path=[path to native libraries]